# Округление до N знаков после запятой в C++

Tags: c++, округление

Решаю задачу на округление до N знаков после запятой. С функцией round() получается округлить только до 5 знаков после запятой, а требуется округлить более точно. Как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    double e =  2.7182818284590452353602875;
    cin >> a;
    e = round(e * pow(10, a)) / pow(10, a);

    cout << e << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *Округлить* или *вывести на экран*? Это разные вещи... Просто по умолчанию выводятся 6 цифр, и это очень напоминает ваши "5 знаков после запятой". Привели бы вы код...

Comment: Код добавил. Кратко поясню саму задачу. Выведите в выходной файл округленное до n знаков после десятичной точки число E. В данной задаче будем считать, что число Е в точности равно 2.7182818284590452353602875.

Comment: `#include <iomanip> ... std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(a) << e;`

Comment: Афигеть, как это работает, можешь немного пояснить то, что ты написал? Я недавно только начал изучать C++ и пока мало что понимаю

Comment: @RealReandy, ну вот как раз повод продолжить изучение, всего-то две функции добавили, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Answer (score 2):

Для более точного округления до `N` знаков после запятой можно воспользоваться функцией `setprecision()` из заголовочного файла `iomanip`. Эта функция принимает на вход количество знаков после запятой, до которых нужно округлить число, и возвращает поток, который можно использовать для вывода числа с нужным количеством знаков после запятой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    double e = 2.7182818284590452353602875;
    cin >> a;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(a) << e << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь функция `setprecision()` используется вместе с манипулятором `fixed`, который говорит потоку, что нужно выводить число с фиксированной точкой.